# Alinea sol report module sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I am using Sugar CRM 6.5.12 and i have installed two packages SugarForge. SolCRM by Alinea Sol: Project Info from this link ... 
1) Alinea Sol CommonBase v1.2.zip
2) Alinea Sol Reports v3.6.zip

and upload them through module loader.
When i create report then it shows no data​

​and following are screenshots . can you tell me where i am wrong and anything else to do: simple i want to display the account names or simple names , I am just testing this module so that i can use it for my crm . But is does not show any results ​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check the logs in /apps/sugarcrm/htdocs/sugarcrm.log

I had similar issue and found the relationships of my custom module weren't setup properly

Answer (score -1):

Also try using a diffirent browser - mine does not work in google chrome but in firefox they generate!